# STL vector: When vector capacity is increased due to insert, does the old contiguous memory deleted or kept after allocating new contiguous memory?

Tags: c++, vector

Recently got into confusion on whether old memory will be freed or not after STL::vector size is increased.

When stl::vector capacity is increased due to insert, a new contiguous memory is allocated (=2*current vector capacity) and old contents are copied to new memory. And the old memory is freed.

Now recently we get into discussion and some believe that old memory is not freed instead it is kept for reference. So over multiple resize's the stl::vector start accumulating memory which is not really needed.

To my understanding it frees old memory but I don't have any concrete documentation on it. However my understanding may be wrong! I would appreciate if anyone who knows the details,  share the same!

Comment: If you are concerned about whether the memory is actually freed or not, you might want to use a profiler or break on `free()` or `operator delete()` with a debugger to see what's actually happening. I believe that most implementations will allocate a new array, copy everything, and delete the old one, but this is implementation defined, so I don't know. Performancewise, this approach is of course bad because the moving necessitates a lot of move constructors being called, with all the overhead that entails. I believe you can count on the implementation _not_ calling `realloc()` internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know, reallocations invalidate all pointers and iterators to the elements of the `vector`, according to the standard. If the old memory was kept somehow, the pointers and iterators would continue to be valid, since they would point at the same objects as before. Therefore, the standard implicitly says that memory is immediately released.

Of course, this does not mean that the runtime is forced to immediately wipe out that memory. In fact, it will most likely remain as it was until your product is deployed at the customer's site. Then it will explode in his face.

Comment: My question is not about whether iterator are valid or invalid (I agree that we should not use old iterators as a safety to avoid any breaks). I am only concerned whether that old memory is freed or not. I am not able to find any good documentation which explains this concept. Infact documentation is the only way I can convince my seniors which are reluctant to agree....

Comment: @pitnal As I say, if memory was not released (freed, if you prefer), the iterators and specially pointers would remain valid. And you know they are not. You can point them to the appropriate section of the C++ Standard, such as §23.3.6.3/6 or §23.3.6.5/1. But you cannot *test* this because the contents of freed memory is undefined. Usually, especially in release builds, it will remain unchanged until the runtime decides to reuse the memory. The Standard does not force to reuse it at any specific moment.

Answer (score 8):

The `vector` definitely does not keep the memory. The allocator might, or `operator new/delete` might. Even the OS might keep the memory reserved for your program.

Comment: That's exactly my point. But I finding it difficult to prove this! Even my sample program shows that old iterator is valid, may be because it is not yet reclaimed by OS.

Comment: @pitnal: That's because you can't prove it. It's pretty much theoretical, anyway. Since you can't use that memory anymore, the OS will probably take away the RAM allocated when it needs it for other programs. But try to test _that_ in a reproducable way!

Comment: @pitnal Even if the memory has been freed, it might still contain the data of the object that used to be there. That doesn't make that object "valid". In fact, accessing the memory to look at the former object causes undefined behaviour and invalidates the entire program. The way to "prove" implementation-specific properties of the allocator (it's not specified by the standard) is to read its code and prove the properties of that.

Answer (score 0):

from  [N3690](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf)

> 23.3.7.5 vector modifiers [vector.modifiers]
>
> iterator insert(const_iterator position, const T& x);
>
> iterator insert(const_iterator position, T&& x);
>
> iterator insert(const_iterator position, size_type n, const T& x);
>
> template  iterator insert(const_iterator
>   position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
>
> iterator insert(const_iterator position, initializer_list);
>
> template  void emplace_back(Args&&... args);
>
> template  iterator emplace(const_iterator position,
>   Args&&... args);
>
> void push_back(const T& x);
>
> void push_back(T&& x);
>
> 1 Remarks: Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old
>   capacity. If no reallocation happens, all the iterators and references
>   before the insertion point remain valid. If an exception is thrown
>   other than by the copy constructor, move constructor, assignment
>   operator, or move assignment operator of T or by any InputIterator
>   operation there are no effects. If an exception is thrown by the move
>   constructor of a non-CopyInsertable T, the effects are unspecified.
>
> 2 Complexity: The complexity is linear in the number of elements
>   inserted plus the distance to the end of the vector.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Do you mean that the word "reallocation" implies the releasing of the old memory?

Comment: Yes, all objects are kept contiguously in memory, so when a reallocation happens, they have to be copied or moved to the new block, otherwise how could "data()" member function  work? Since the elements are duplicated, there is no reason to not release the memory. Finally, the vector container is a simple runtime-sized array, this says the standard, this is not a datastructure that mantain references to objects distributed anywhere.